# OpenCV - nearest video frame at file position

Tags: c#, opencv, ffmpeg

OpenCV: I have file position in the .ts file (for example 515 486 byte) and I need to know which video frame - which frame index - is the nearest to this file position.

I am using Emgu.CV library in c#.

Comment: without scanning all data upto that point, you *likely* won't be able to know what frame *index* that is. an [mpeg transport stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream) contains *timestamps* but afaik it contains no frame counters

Comment: >without scanning all data upto that point< - When I decode frame by Emgu.CV - is there a possibility to get file position of this decoded video frame?

Comment: OpenCV is not ffmpeg. OpenCV has video I/O for convenience. its video I/O is a very abstract layer on top of ffmpeg and other libraries. it is not supposed to give this information. if you use OpenCV for *what you do there*, you are using the wrong library. use ffmpeg directly. -- if you're on windows anyway, you could use windows media APIs. DSHOW/MSMF is perfectly capable of demuxing containers and decoding streams.